# SQL creating a column for only the latest ID with an additional condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a SQL Server table where I have the following

```
ID   Date_Stamp   Stopper       ProcessStep  Age  
A1   01/01/2019   DO_NOT_USE    Complete
A1   31/12/2019   New           Enter
A2   02/01/2019   New           Enter        What is the age?
A3   06/01/2019   New           Enter    
A4   01/01/2019   New           Enter
A4   02/01/2019   New           Process
A4   03/01/2019   New           Review       What is the age? 
A5   17/01/2019   New           Enter
```

Can anyone tell my how can I use SQL to add a column that calculates the age of the latest process for each ID, ignoring all ID's where the Stopper says "DO_NOT_USE" please?

I also need the whole table

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (2) How is "age" calculated?

Comment: Hi Gordon age = Date Today - Date_Stamp

Comment: @T17. . . Why `A3` & `A5` doesn't have a age ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number with `not exists` :

```
select t.*, 
       (case when seq = 1 and not exists (select 1 
                                          from table t1 
                                          where t1.id = t.id and t1.stopper = 'do_not_use'
                                         )
             then datediff(dd, Date_Stamp, GETDATE()) 
        end) as age
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
order by id;
```

**EDIT** : Using *window* function :

```
select t.*, 
       (case when seq = 1 and all_cnt = stopper_chk 
             then datediff(dd, Date_Stamp, getdate()) 
        end) as age
from (select t.*, 
            row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seq,
            count(case when t.stopper = 'do_not_use' then null else 1 end) over (partition by id) as stopper_chk, 
            count(*) over (partition by id) as all_cnt
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh, apologies still quite new to SQL so "t" is the name name of the table?

Comment: @T17. . . Yes it is name of table inform of table alias.

Comment: so if the table name was "QWERTY" then I should just replace "t" with "Qwerty"?

Comment: @T17. . . No, you need to change `table` with `QWERTY`.

Comment: thanks Yogesh it's the query is working but when I select the table again I can't see the age column. How can I make this change permanent?

Comment: @T17. . . This is select query & will not change underlying table. You can create a view,

Comment: Is it possible to change the underlying table with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE_STAMP DESC) RN,* FROM TABLENAME 
 WHERE STOPPER!='DO_NOT_USE' 
 ) SELECT ID,Date_Stamp ,Stopper,ProcessStep,DATEDIFF(DD,Date_Stamp,GETDATE()) AGE_DAY 
 FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

[For Reference Kindly check in attached link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28746dc69831ccbf2825569f36ce5234)

Comment: Hi Somendra, thanks for the response. The problem with this solution is we lose the row which says "Do_not_use". I'd want to keep it